# MySQL join on data where right side has prepended string

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a feeling there's an easy solution to this problem, but I can't figure out how to word it correctly to get the answer I'm looking for from Google.

I need to join two tables where the field in *table 1* I want to use to join is an integer lets say **55** for this example, and *table 2*'s field is a string that follows this template: **node/#** where **#** is **55** from *table 1*.

Ordinarily if the data was the same  I'd do

```
JOIN table1  t1 ON t1.id = table2.id
```

But in pseudo I want to do

```
JOIN table1 t1 ON #{node/}+t1.id = table2.id
```

Where I'm manually adding ***node/*** onto the value on table 1 so that it will then match the value in table 2. But I don't know if that's even possible.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: That's perfectly possible to join on a custom expression, here you just need to cast and concat : 
concat("node/", cast(t1.id as varchar))

Comment: @Logar the `concat` bit worked, however using `cast(.. as varchar)` threw me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON CONCAT('node/', t1.id) = t2.id
```

Comment: knew it would be something simple. Thanks